# How to "export" transformations applied to an SVG object, to another SVG object, using Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

How can I take the transformations that I've applied so far to an SVG image object (i.e. consecutive scaling, dragging, rotation transformations) and apply them to a new SVG image added to the page?

The SVG element that I want to read the transformations of, looks like this:

```
<svg height="598" version="1.1" width="462" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc>
    <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
    <image x="139.26470588235293" y="180.5" width="226.47058823529412" height="150" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="./gallery/viewport/cmf_52a45ec2e13207277.jpg" transform="matrix(0.8877,0.4605,-0.4605,0.8877,146.0177,-87.5714)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" stroke-width="0.64"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: why not just get the image element by getElementById()  and then use image1.getAttribute('transform') ?

Comment: I imagine its pretty much the same in Raph, have you tried element.transform() ?

Comment: If there are more complex things you need to figure than this example, another thought could be to clone it, change the href, then append it.